# printf, adding a header to an output file

Tags: c, printf

I have

```
printf("%12.8f, %12.8f, %6.3f, %04u/%02u/%02u   %i:%i:4.2f\n",sbet.longitude1,sbet.latitude1,sbet.altitude ,myyear,mymonth, myday, sbet.hour, sbet.minute, sbet.second);
```

inside an If statement. And it produces exactly what i want line by line.  But now i want to add a header/title to the very top.  Do i use another printf statement?  When i tried a simple

```
printf("Longitude,", "Latitude," "Elevation," , "UTC Time");
```

that didn't give me what i wanted, it just put only "Longitude,"  on each line along with the rest of the parameters in the other printf statement.

Basically i want to have this as the result

```
Longitude,   Latitude,   Elevation,   UTC Time
-50.62596165,  67.01225899, 82.948, 2012/05/08   10:0:0.04
-50.62596152,  67.01225906, 82.949, 2012/05/08   10:0:1.04
-50.62596154,  67.01225906, 82.950, 2012/05/08   10:0:2.04
-50.62596148,  67.01225902, 82.951, 2012/05/08   10:0:3.04
-50.62596154,  67.01225907, 82.952, 2012/05/08   10:0:4.04
-50.62596160,  67.01225911, 82.952, 2012/05/08   10:0:5.04
```

This is the full program (below).  It contains a couple if statements.  I tried putting

```
printf( "Longitude, Latitude, Elevation , UTC Time\n");
```

before both if statements, but i got the same results, with having the four word title on each line instead of just one line at the top.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "applanix_data.h"
#include "applanix_pos_out.h"

#define DEGREES2RADIANS  (3.141592654 / 180.0)

int output_group_1(FILE *fp,
               FILE *fpout,
               unsigned short myyear,
               unsigned short mymonth,
               unsigned short myday,
               double time_sod,
               double double_time_met)
{
struct applanix_data_group1 data1;
struct pospacsbet sbet;

  if(fread(&data1,sizeof(struct applanix_data_group1),1,fp)==1)
 {
    sbet.gpstime = time_sod;
    sbet.latitude = data1.latitude * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.longitude = data1.longitude * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.altitude = data1.altitude;
    sbet.x_velocity = data1.eVelocity;
    sbet.y_velocity = data1.nVelocity;
    sbet.z_velocity = data1.dVelocity;
    sbet.roll = data1.aircraftRoll * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.pitch = data1.aircraftPitch * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.platform_heading = data1.aircraftHeading * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.wander_angle = data1.aircraftWanderAngle * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.x_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftTransverseAcceleration;
    sbet.y_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftLongitudinalAcceleration;
    sbet.z_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftDownAcceleration;
    sbet.x_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftAngularRateAboutDownAxis;
    sbet.y_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftLongitudinalAcceleration;
    sbet.z_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftAngularRateAboutDownAxis;

    if(fwrite(&sbet,sizeof(struct pospacsbet),1,fpout)!=1)
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error writing POSPAC SBET output!\n");
         exit(-2);
      }

    sbet.latitude1 = sbet.latitude * (180/3.141592654);
    sbet.longitude1 = sbet.longitude * (180/3.14592654);
    sbet.day = sbet.gpstime/86400;
    sbet.time = sbet.gpstime/86400;
    sbet.hour1 = (sbet.time - sbet.day);
    sbet.hour = sbet.hour1*24;
    sbet.time = sbet.hour1*24;
    sbet.minute1 = (sbet.time - sbet.hour);
    sbet.minute = sbet.minute1*60;
    sbet.time = sbet.minute1 * 60;
    sbet.second1 = (sbet.time - sbet.minute);
    sbet.second = sbet.second1*60;

    printf("%12.8f, %12.8f, %6.3f, %04u/%02u/%02u   %i:%i:%4.2f\n",sbet.longitude1,sbet.latitude1,sbet.altitude,myyear,mymonth, myday, sbet.hour, sbet.minute, sbet.second);
    return 0;
 }
  else
 return -1;
}
```

I call the function like this

unix>  gcc -o applanixraw2out applanixraw2out.c

unix>  ./applanixraw2out applanix_raw_20120508.bin > test.txt

Comment: `printf("Longitude,   Latitude,   Elevation,   UTC Time\n");`? Maybe I am miss understanding.

Comment: If a newline was all that you couldn't emit, how did you manage `printf("%12.8f, %12.8f, %6.3f, %04u/%02u/%02u   %i:%i:4.2f\n", ...`?

Comment: Do you use any kind of a loop? Because you say, that it is printed each line. Just use `printf` before your loop starts to print the header.

Comment: I added the rest of the program for reference

Comment: Please post the part of the code, where you call this function as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("Longitude,   Latitude,   Elevation,   UTC Time\n");
```

Comment: That is almost what i want, but that puts Longitude, Latitude, Elevation, UTC Time on every line above its respective values.  I want just one line at the very top.

Comment: That must be because you have it inside a loop? If so, put the heading before the loop.... and don't forget the '\n' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Longitude, Latitude Elevation, UTC Time"\n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the `if(fread ...`, use a formatted header

```
printf("%-12s, %-12s, %-6s, %-12s\n", "Longitude", "Latitude", "Elevation", "UTC Time");
```

You can then readily adjust the spacing to match most of your

```
printf("%12.8f, %12.8f, %6.3f ...
```

Comment: That doesn't work, (i mean it works, just not what im lookng for)  i mean im still getting the "Longitude etc" line on every line.  I want it ONLY on the very top line of the output

Comment: Yes, of course, when I said before the "if(fread ...," I should have said outside the loop that is calling the function `output_group_1()`, maybe just after a successful open of `FILE *fp`.

Comment: BTW: Recommend a better PI, either M_PI from math.h or 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

Comment: BTW2: Do you want 'sbet.time = sbet.gpstime%86400'?  '%' rather than '/'?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my simple library libTprint: https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint, it does exactly what you want. Take a look at the code - it's quite simple and you should be able to understand how it works.

Hope it helps !